# Can someone please translate this, I think it is seal script? (Characters identified: 天神貴者太乙)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

[image: Chinese Prayer]

I think this is a prayer in seal script but I have not been able to find the characters anywhere.
Can anyone tell me what it says in Chinese and English?
Thanks!

Comment: Some characters here look a bit more like bronze inscriptions to me. Maybe it might be a combination of the bronze and seal script together?

Comment: @prismcool this is almost certainly just "bronze inscriptions", but we don't have a tag for this.

Comment: @dROOOze Yeah, I can tell because digging further, I can tell that this is just some kind of font made to emulate the bronze script style. Because there's no way 太 existed at the time of the bronzeware script.

Comment: So it is bronze inscriptions not seal script?
What does it mean?
Is there a site where I can look up other characters like it?
Thanks !!!

Comment: @user38695 I personally would recommend https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/ and https://zi.tools/ if you need a free database of ancient forms of characters. Always gets the job done for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got
Taiyi the noblest of Gods in heaven
Is that anywhere close?